# Segment the signup process to allow email verification at a later time

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure B2C for our Identity provider, but it is clear that users are finding the process a bit clunky. Mostly this appears to be because of the synchronous nature of the signup process.

We do want to verify the email address and MFA phone number, but ideally not at the point at which they are entered. Is there a way that we can leverage a graph API call to deal with this, or use a custom policy to achieve the same?

[image]

We would also like a clear separation of the signup/signin process. Such that a user can be directed to these pages directly and they can also be branded.

Comment: Hi @nat: Are you planning to verify the email address and phone number during the sign-up flow at all or later during a sign-in flow or out-of-band?

Comment: hi @chris, ideally we would capture the email (and possibly MFA phone) at the beginning of a new business journey, and then validate it at the end - or lock down the servicing area until this validation is complete. - i added an image in the original post to explain further - basically an asynchronous journey to avoid dropouts. if people have a slow polling email or no access to it immediately, we will likely lose their business

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to implement this with two custom policies:

1. A sign-up policy that prompts the new customer for the email address and the phone number and creates a new user with these marked as unverified. This custom policy can be invoked at the **Account Creation** step.
2. A verification policy that verifies the unverified email address, via the built-in email message, and then the unverified phone number, via the built-in phone call or text message. This custom policy can be invoked at the **Application Complete** step.

Note that it isn't the sign-up policy that sends the verification code but the verification policy that sends it. I don't know if this is acceptable for the desired experience but the custom policy that sends the verification code must be the same one that validates it.

(There is an alternate flow where after the sign-up policy has completed, your end application sends a custom email message, containing a verification link, which when opened by the end user is validated by your end application and then the verification policy -- minus the email verification step since the email address has already been verified -- is started).

If this proposed solution is interesting to you, then I can attempt to provide the full details of the custom policies based on one of [the custom policy starter packs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack).

**Updated on 15 February 2019**

I've published the following custom policy samples to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-samples). The second and third policies implement the above flow.

**sign_up_sign_in**

Sign-up for a local account using an e-mail address *and* a phone number. The end user is prompted for verification of the e-mail address and the phone number.

Sign-in for a local account using an e-mail address *or* a phone number. If the e-mail address hasn't been verified, then the end user is prompted for verification of the e-mail address. If the phone number hasn't been verified, then the end user is prompted for verification of the phone number.

**sign_up_without_verification**

Sign-up for a local account using an e-mail address *and* a phone number. The end user is *not* prompted for verification of the e-mail address or the phone number.

**sign_in_with_verification**

Sign-in for a local account using an e-mail address *or* a phone number. If the e-mail address hasn't been verified, then the end user is prompted for verification of the e-mail address. If the phone number hasn't been verified, then the end user is prompted for verification of the phone number.

Comment: hi @chris thanks for that. I would certainly be interested in more info on both of those. I think that if the verification policy has to send out the link - we may be in a similar position with synchronously verifying the email - but the sales process would have completed so it may be less of an issue at that point - and being able to do this with policies alone is ideal. However the end application sending the verification link would presumably allow for the customisation of the verification email and such.

Comment: is there somewhere you can point me for information on this chris, as I am not having much luck with the starter packs.

Comment: Hi @nat I've updated the above answer with links to the custom policies that implement the proposed flow.

Comment: Hi @chris, thanks very much for that I will give it a try.